# Javascript arrow function inside case statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, arrow-functions

I wish to know how to implement an arrow function inside a case statement.
Please what is the way to obtain for example 15 into 'result' if I do something similar?

```
var result = num.calculate('+');
```

```js
var num = {
  x: 12,
  y: 3,
  calculate: function(operation) {
    var fn;
    switch (operation) {
      case '+':
        fn = function() {
          return this.x + this.y
        };
        break;
      case '-':
        fn = function() {
          return this.x - this.y
        };
        break;
      default:
        fn = function() {};
    }
    return fn();
  }
}
```

Comment: `function() { return this.x + this.y};` becomes `() => { return this.x + this.y}` or `() => this.x + this.y`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: I'm not convinced the dupe is accurate. It seems it's not about `calculate` being an arrow function but `calculate` having arrow functions inside it.

Comment: The problem is that he can't access the `x` and `y` in those functions. That dupe covers that.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` and `y` properties exist on the calling context, the `num` object - either reference `num.x`, or when calling the function, use `fn.call(num)` so that the `this` inside the function refers to the `num` object:

```js
var num = {
  x: 12,
  y: 3,
  calculate: function(operation) {
    var fn;
    switch (operation) {
      case '+':
        fn = function() {
          return this.x + this.y
        };
        break;
      case '-':
        fn = function() {
          return this.x - this.y
        };
        break;
      default:
        fn = function() {};
    }
    return fn.call(num);
  }
}



risult = num.calculate('+');
console.log(risult);
```

You could also use arrow functions, so that the `this` is inherited from the outer scope instead, eg `fn = () => this.x + this.y`:

```js
var num = {
  x: 12,
  y: 3,
  calculate: function(operation) {
    var fn;
    switch (operation) {
      case '+':
        fn = () => this.x + this.y
        break;
      case '-':
        fn = () => this.x - this.y;
        break;
      default:
        fn = function() {};
    }
    return fn();
  }
}



risult = num.calculate('+');
console.log(risult);
```

But `switch` is quite verbose and can be pretty error-prone. How about using an object indexed by `operation` instead (and use correct spelling to prevent bugs, use `result`, not `risult`):

```js
const fns = {
  '+': () => num.x + num.y,
  '-': () => num.x - num.y,
};
var num = {
  x: 12,
  y: 3,
  calculate: operation => {
    const fn = fns[operation] || (() => null);
    return fn();
  }
};
const result = num.calculate('+');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wonderful! Problem solved in 3 minutes!!! :)
Thank you very much